# Solving a coupled system of linear ODEs (one second order, the other first order)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have two coupled ODEs for $T(x)$ and $t(x)$:

$$\frac{d^2 T(x)}{d x^2}-\beta (T(x)-t(x))+K=0 \tag 1$$

$$\frac{d t(x)}{dx}-\alpha(T(x)-t(x))=0 \tag 2$$

$\alpha, \beta$ and $K$ are constants $>0$. Also, it is known that $t(x=0)=t_i$. Additionally, for $(1)$ we know:

$$\frac{d T(x=0)}{d x}=\frac{d T(x=L)}{d x} = 0$$

I need to determine $T(x)$ and $t(x)$.  Can anyone suggest a way towards moving ahead with this problem ?

Probably this system of coupled equations can be solved using the matrix method, but I am not aware of it. I normally solve a single equation using either the method of integrating factor or using a characteristic equation and finding the roots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{d^2 T(x)}{d x^2}-\beta (T(x)-t(x))+K=0 \tag 1$$

$$\frac{d t(x)}{dx}-\alpha(T(x)-t(x))=0 \tag 2$$

HINT :

From $(2) \qquad T=\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{d t}{dx}+t$

$\frac{d^2T}{dx^2}=\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{d^3t}{dx^3}+\frac{d^2t}{dx^2}$

Puting them into $(1)$ :

$\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{d^3t}{dx^3}+\frac{d^2t}{dx^2}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\frac{d t}{dx} +K=0$

$$\frac{d^3t}{dx^3}+\alpha\frac{d^2t}{dx^2}-\beta\frac{d t}{dx} +\alpha K=0$$
This is a linear ODE with constant coefficients. I suppose that you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes I can now solve this and substitute back the $t(x)$ solution to $(1)$ to get $T(x)$. Out of the three undetermined constant sone gets evaluated due to $t(x=0)=t_i$. The other two will be evaluated based on the boundary conditions of $T$ ?

Comment: Yes, $T(x)=\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{d t(x)}{dx}+t(x)$ and the constants have to be evaluated according to the conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Hint :

Substitute $T(x)=\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{d t(x)}{dx}+t(x)$ in $(1)$ :

$$  \frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{d^3t(x)}{dx^3}+\frac{d^2t(x)}{dx^2}-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\frac{d t(x)}{dx} +K = 0$$

Then solve for $\frac{dt(x)}{dx}$.