# Solving a coupled system of linear ODEs one second order, the other first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, discrete-optimization, weighted-least-squares

i want to find Aerodynamic center (y,z) and its moment(M ac) for vehicle , so i searched a lot , and i found these information .

Aerodynamic center position  doesn't change wrt angle , drag ,lift forces , pitch moment acts at

i 've done cfd simulations for various angle to get drag ,lift ,moment values ,and i ve made curve fitting for them

so i ve  y,z,M ac  unknowns while  N,A,Mo are known for discrete data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFIH1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9x2C.png)

so i think here i 've coupled system first and second order ,

**so how can i solve them ?**

**if i took more derivatives will it yield to better solution ?**

**can i apply least square optimization as multi objective function ? and how**

i actually tried something which wast right , that i solved system using cramer rule  rule , i think that made linearization so i didn't get good result ,am i right ?

i came across into similar question but i cant relate solution to my problem

[Solving a coupled system of linear ODEs (one second order, the other first order)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3797100/solving-a-coupled-system-of-linear-odes-one-second-order-the-other-first-order)

i think we cant solve 2 differential equations when one derived from another so i find another equation .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDion.png)

i think i ve under determined differential equation , i don't know if least square optimization can solve it

update 2 , i  dont think i ve uder determined system , because with eq 2 , 5  i ve two unknowns y , z with two equations

Comment: I am just a beginner, so please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems your "real" system is eq. (1) and the line directly below it? Eq. (2) and (3) are simply applications of these two, so they should not contain any additional information. That is, they are perhaps steps toward a solution rather than a system on their own, wouldn't you agree?

This means that since you have four unknown functions, but only one equation (and some constraints on the derivatives) there is a huge number of possible combinations of functions that can work as solutions.

Comment: Note also that you have assumed that the derivative of $Mac$ is $0$, which means that the function is constant, is this what you want? Also, are you sure that this should not be a system of PDEs instead? Usually aerodynamics problems are pdes I think, unless they are extremely simplified? Especially since you have $x$, $y$ and $z$ in the equations, it gets kinda confusing as to what sort of system this is; perhaps you could specify the functions and variables involved explicitly?

Comment: I really think you need some additional information from the physical context, i.e. more relations among the functions in the system, that do not come from simply differentiating the first equation.

But I guess I can have misunderstood something, since I'm just a beginner xD

Comment: Please also note that it is nice if we can read the equations directly in the post, without having to click on a link :)

Comment: By the way, how did you apply cramer's rule here?

Comment: @AntimatterHedgehog thanks for your concern actually , sorry for clicking on link but i dont know how to write equations here , yes Mac is 0 , i actually made mistake only y z are constants here , there is no x , forces are only function of ceta so the variable is only one so there is no need for partial derivatives ,  and for applying cramer rule the result will be (y,z,Mo) this is column, coeffcient matrix will be (Nceta  ,  -Aceta , -1) this is first row(for simplicity i just typed here first row)   , and then vector ( -Mo,d/dceta  Mo , - d/dceta dceta Mo) ,,  i saw this method in book

Comment: @AntimatterHedgehog the first equation  is not constant because , N , A , Mo are variables of ceta

Comment: i ve searched for more equation and i come across one so i edited my problem

Comment: I think the system is over-determined, i.e. you have three unknowns (N, A, Mo or x, y, Mac) but essentially only two equations. Are you looking to determine z, y, and Mac given that N, A and Mo are given, or is it the other way around? If you want to determine z, y, Mac when you know the functions N, A, Mo, then there is no need for a differential equation! However, if all six of these are unknown, you will need a system of six equations.

Comment: I really recommend asking at the physics forum -- https://physics.stackexchange.com. They can help you set up the system of equations properly :)

Comment: @AntimatterHedgehog thanks for your reply , yes i want to know , y ,z ,mac , do u mean that if i want to find coefficients i dont need differential equation and can be solved with cramer rule ?

Comment: @AntimatterHedgehog but i ve constrain where d/dceta ( Mac)  = 0 , how can i apply it to them then